# I need to check that a phone and email are unique and there are not equal when they are introduce in a form

Tags: angular, angular-forms

This is the HTML

```
<div class="form">
  <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
  <input type="text" id="nombre" [(ngModel)]="nuevoContacto.nombre">

  <label for="telefono">Telefono</label>
  <input type="text" id="telefono" [(ngModel)]="nuevoContacto.telefono">

  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" id="email" [(ngModel)]="nuevoContacto.email">

  <button (click)="recogerDatosForm()">Guardar</button>


</div>
```

this is the TS

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-formulario',
  templateUrl: './formulario.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./formulario.component.css']
})
export class FormularioComponent {

  @Output() contactoEmitido: EventEmitter<Contacto>
  nuevoContacto: Contacto = { nombre: "", telefono: 0, email: "" }

  constructor () {
    this.contactoEmitido = new EventEmitter();
  }

  recogerDatosForm () {
    this.contactoEmitido.emit(this.nuevoContacto);
    this.nuevoContacto = { nombre: "", telefono: 0, email: "" } //
  }
}
```

I would like to know how to get an alert if the user type a phone number or email that already exist. Thanks!

Comment: Unique compared to what? Server data? App data?

Comment: In case server data, this should help you... https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-async-validators-to-template-driven-forms

Comment: typically you would have your own database in order to check against.